# How to call a local service in mvc portlet?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have created a my-services-portlet in which i have AbcService, which I am calling from my templates like this

```
#set ($VeloToolsService = $serviceLocator.findService('my-services-portlet, 'com.mycompany.services.AbcServiceLocalService'))

#set ($article = $AbcService.getArticle($list))
$journalContentUtil.getContent($article.groupId, $article.articleId, 'view', $themeDisplay.language-id, $xmlRequest)
```

Now due to new requirement, i need to call the same service from another custom mvc portlet. I am not able to the service handle for the service. what is the proper way to get the service handle? so that i can call my existing service from the portlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the AbcService-service.jar file from first portlet to tomcat/lib/ext folder, restart liferay, and you get access to the service classes.

See http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4585610 the answer from Mika Koivisto.